Continuity of the evaluation map defined on $X \times C(X,Y)$
I'm currently reading chapter 7 of the book Topology by Munkres and was wondering if my "proof" for one of the theorems works.
In particular, it is the theorem that states that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has the compact-open topology, then the evaluation map $e: X \times \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ defined by $e(x,f) = f(x)$ is continuous.
Here's my attempted proof:
Let $U, V$ be open subsets of $X$, $Y$, respectively. Since $X$ is locally compact, there exists a compact subspace $C$ of $X$ containing $U$. Then $\forall\: (x,f) \in U \times S(C,V)$, $e(x,f) = f(x)$ belongs to $V$ by definition (S(C,V) is a basis element for the compact-open topology on $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ consisting of $f \in \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ such that $f(x) \in V$, $\forall\: x \in C$). That is, $U \times S(C,V) \subset e^{-1}(V)$. Thus, for every open set $V$ of $Y$, $e^{-1}(V)$ is open.
One red flag I can think of is the fact that I didn't use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff, at least not explicitly.
Any opinions are welcome!
Thanks in advance!

If $U$ is $X$, then $C$ is $X$ and you are assuming $X$ is compact.

If I’m not mistaken, X being locally compact means that every point x of X has a neighborhood contained in a compact subspace of X.

This doesn’t make much sense. You’re messing up all sorts of orders of quantifiers. To prove $e$ is continuous, you’re supposed to show that $e^{-1}(V)$ is open for any open $V \subset Y$. To do that, you need to show whenever $(x, f) \in e^{-1}(V)$ (i.e., whenever $f(x) \in V$), there exists a basic open neighborhood of $(x, f)$ contained in $e^{-1}(V)$, or, to put it another way, there exists $U \subset X$ open, $C \subset X$ compact, and $V’ \subset Y$ open, s.t. $(x, f) \in U \times S(C, V’) \subset e^{-1}(V)$. You certainly cannot just fix an $U$ to start with.

That makes so much sense! Thank you!

@AP Remember to accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Here is a corrected proof:
Let $V \subset Y$ be open. We need to show $e^{-1}(V)$ is open. Let $(x, f) \in e^{-1}(V)$. It suffices to show that there exists $U \subset X$ open, $C \subset X$ compact, and $V’ \subset Y$ open, s.t. $(x, f) \in U \times S(C, V’) \subset e^{-1}(V)$.
Since $(x, f) \in e^{-1}(V)$, we have $f(x) \in V$. Since $f$ is continuous and $V$ is open, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. As $X$ is an LCH space, it is in particular regular, so there exists disjoint open $U’, U’’ \subset X$ s.t. $x \in U’$ and $X \setminus f^{-1}(V) \subset U’’$. Again, as $X$ is an LCH space, there exists $U’’’ \subset X$, open neighborhood of $x$, s.t. $\overline{U’’’}$ is compact. Let $U = U’ \cap U’’’$, $C = \overline{U}$, and $V’ = V$.
Clearly, $x \in U$. Since $C$ is a closed subset of $\overline{U’’’}$, it is compact. Furthermore, as $U \subset U’ \subset X \setminus U’’$, and the latter set is closed, we have $C = \overline{U} \subset X \setminus U’’ \subset f^{-1}(V)$, i.e., $f(C) \subset V$, or $f \in S(C, V)$. So indeed $(x, f) \in U \times S(C, V)$.
Finally, let $(x’, f’) \in U \times S(C, V)$. We need to show $f’(x’) \in V$ (i.e., we need to show $U \times S(C, V) \subset e^{-1}(V)$). But $U \subset C$, so $f’(x’) \in f’(U) \subset f’(C) \subset V$, which proves the claim.
